# JQuery Ajax Pool

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Working on a single page application, and I am currently building a JQuery, ajax function for all of my calls to go through.

For a typical page I might have 3 ajax calls. My idea is if a users internet goes out to hold these ajax calls in an array. And then do a timer and keep checking if the user has internet. Once they have internet do the calls. So no calls are run when the user is offline (except for the check for internet one) and once their back online do what they wanted. So in my beforeSend I have this.

```
beforeSend : function($xhr)
{
    self.ajaxPool.push($xhr);

    if(!self.validateConnection())
    {
        console.log(self.ajaxPool);
    }
}
```

So my question is when I get connection back, and loop through my array to each `$xhr` object what function can I call on it to say, 'Hey do what you were supposed to now'? For example `$xhr.complete()`? I've done a console log on the pool to look at the objects when connection is down but none of the functions it has look like they'd do the trick.

Comment: Couldn't you just add a state variable to the xhr variable? if($xhr.doSend){ //send it }else{ //pool it } ... and then when the pool does the send just do $xhr.doSend=true right before you send it?

Comment: But how do you //send it ? what do you actually do in there to send it?

Comment: As far as I know the only way would be to call $.ajax again with the original settings. So maybe instead of pushing the xhr you just push the options... Or alternatively, I just have a running queue that only gets executed when there is a connection. I just posted an answer with more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ditch the beforeSend entirely since you're using a pool anyways and do something like this...

```
//where you want to make your initial request somewhere in code
//do this INSTEAD of calling $.ajax(options)
ajaxPool.push(options);

//an interval to handle the queue
setInterval(function(){
    //nothing in the pool so do nothing
    if(ajaxPool.length < 1) return;
    //not online so don't try to send
    if(!validateConnection()) return;
    //hey we're online lets make the ajax request
    doAjax(ajaxPool.shift());
},200);

function doAjax(options){
    //add call backs since you seem to be using a single call back
    options.complete=function(data){ ... };

    //do call
    $.ajax(options);
}
```

You could make this more OOP and you could pause the interval when you know it's not being used, but I think this gets the basic concept across.

Comment: changed from pop to shift to keep the requests in order in the queue. push to the end. pull (shift) from the beginning.

Comment: Ahhhh so push the json's into an array! I'll implement this totally different but your idea is genius! Thanks for the head start I really appreciate it! +1 accept!

Comment: I've implemented this on my site and it is beyond dope. Brilliant idea thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I been using this **Offline JS** for my RIA applications. It's really reliable for your offline scenarios

- Monitors ajax requests looking for failure
- Confirms the connection status by requesting an image or fake resource
- Automatically grabs ajax requests made while the connection is down and remakes them after the connection is restored.

https://github.com/HubSpot/offline

Comment: Sorry the only third party scripts I can use with this client is jquery